# Expected number of rounds needed until a winner is declare in Rock, Paper, Scissors.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

> A game of Rock, Paper, Scissors is usually played with 2 or more (*n*) people. If when all *n* people reveal their play and only 1 or all 3 options appear, that round is deemed indecisive, and they just play again. If when all *n* people reveal their play and two of the three options appear, that round is decisive, and those with the winning play continue and those with the losing play are eliminated. Playing continues until only one person remains.

So I'm a bit confused by how to do calculate the following parts:

> 1. Assuming three initial players, compute the probability that the first round is decisive.
> 2. Assuming three initial players, compute analytically the expected number of rounds needed until a winner is declared.

I got 2/3 for 1), because there's 1/3 probability the first round is indecisive and 1/3 that any round is indecisive.

For 2), I got 2(n - 1) / 3^n = 2 / 9 for n = 2 to consider cases where a winner is declared after a round with all three people, and the case where the first decisive round leaves 2 people before the winner is declared.

However, my reasoning seems too simple, and I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: Please edit to explain your computation for part $1$.  Note that your solution for part $2$ doesn't make sense, what's $n$?  The answer is meant to be a number.